# How to make items within flex more responsive?

Tags: css, responsive-design, flexbox, antd

I have a header layout and I have put items within a flex `Row & Col` item. Currently the Col responsiveness is not perfect but what I'm trying to understand more is how to make the elements within a `Col` more responsive within. Is the correct way to use div?

I want it to be able to grow and always sit within Col however when I scale it down to different screen size it renders outside

Webview
https://tp2d7.csb.app/

[image: Edit Custom trigger - Ant Design Demo]

```
        <Row>
          <Col
            xs={1}
            sm={2}
            md={3}
            lg={4}
            style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }}
          >
            <Avatar />
          </Col>
          <Col
            xs={4}
            sm={8}
            md={10}
            lg={12}
            style={{ backgroundColor: "blue" }}
          >
            <Avatar />
          </Col>
          <Col
            xs={2}
            sm={4}
            md={6}
            lg={8}
            style={{ backgroundColor: "green" }}
          >
            <div
              style={{
                justifyContent: "flex-end",
                display: "flex"
              }}
            >
              <div style={{ padding: "0 6px" }}>
                <Avatar />{" "}
              </div>
              <div style={{ padding: "0 6px" }}>
                <Avatar />{" "}
              </div>
              <div style={{ padding: "0 6px" }}>
                <Avatar />{" "}
              </div>
              <div style={{ padding: "0 6px" }}>
                <Avatar />{" "}
              </div>
            </div>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the size of the Avatar component, maybe define it with `em` or `rem` units.
Also declaring that div as a `flexbox` does not achieve much, unless you want it to be able to wrap itself. 
You have also defined lesser column width for `xs` size and more for `lg` size. It does not make much sense to me. Try to switch it (`xs = {4}  lg={2}`).

Add this property with other flex styles defined and see if the effect is desired
`flexWrap: 'wrap'`

Comment: where do I put flexWrap: wrap property? within the Col or div?

Comment: @Freddy. in the `div`, along with the `justifyContent`property